# How can I enforce url conventions for my web application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes

As an architect, so that the application I'm building has a REST-compliant url scheme that represents the domain accurately, I want a way to enforce convention that has the following properties:

- pit of success (easier for dev to do it right than to do it wrong)
- follows class convention, unless it doesn't, in which case it's overridable
- routes are stored in a centralized location in the codebase
- takes advantage of type system (strongly-typed controller actions instead of inspecting request variables for parameters inside the action)
- versionable

In my experience, class naming and action naming conventions fall apart eventually (the domain model doesn't exactly follow the object model, or developers find it difficult to debug routes), and the application reverts to attribute routing. Attribute routing has a number of drawbacks, and can become a wild west environment where several URL styles grow together.

What's out there to solve this seemingly common problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're looking for a third option that doesn't exist. Traditional routing and attribute routing pretty much cover all the scenarios. Which you use is really just about weighing the pros and cons of each.

Traditional routing is the conventions-based approach, so if you're looking for something devs don't have to think about, then that's it. The default is the `/controller/action` format, but you can create other routes for specific scenarios where you want something else. All the routes are centralized in `RouteConfig.cs`, and the routing-related helpers in `HtmlHelper` and `UrlHelper` can be called as strongly-typed: `Html.ActionLink<FooController>(m => m.Index(), "Foo")`.

About the only item not ticked off your list is "versionable", but I'm not sure how you would expect that to work anyways? My mind instantly goes to Web Api and prefixing routes with something like `v1`, `v2`, etc. If that's what you're talking about, you can easily do that as well with traditional routing.

If you want something more flexible, that's where attribute routing comes in, and in truth, you can mix and match traditional routing and attribute routing to get the best of both worlds. Attribute routing is a lot less formalized, but that's kind of the point.

Ultimately, this just comes down to standards within your organization though. There is no programming language, framework, or system of routing that will ever lock you in to one way of doing things for all time. If you want standardization, you have to enforce standardization. This is where things like code reviews, QA, etc. come in. You shouldn't expect a framework to solve institutional problems for you, because it never will.